# Busquedas en un formulario en laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Aunque te doy las gracias no es la respuesta que estoy buscando a mi problema. Creo que no me he explicado adecuadamente.
He agregado el código tanto de la ruta como del formulario para hacernos una idea de la situación en la que me encuentro.

Mi problema radica en la variable `$search='tipo'`.

Por lo tanto cómo podría imprimir esta variable, para que cuando yo haga lo siguiente:

```
<form action="{{route($search)}}" method="post">
    @csrf
    <input type="hidden" name="prueba" value="prueba">
    <button type="submit">Submmit Prueba</button>
</form>
```

Me lo imprima de la manera correcta mediante la variable :

```
<form action="http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/productos" method="post">
    @csrf
    <input type="hidden" name="prueba" value="prueba">
    <button type="submit">Submmit Prueba</button>
</form>
```

Y no poniendo lo siguiente

```
<form action="{{route('tipo')}}" method="post">
    @csrf
    <input type="hidden" name="prueba" value="prueba">
    <button type="submit">Submmit Prueba</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De la [documentación](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/helpers#method-route).
Si la ruta acepta parámetros, puede pasarlos como el segundo argumento del método:

```
$url = route('routeName', ['id' => 1]);
```

Lo que para tu ruta:

```
Route::post('admin/productos/{tipo?}',[
    'as'=>'tipo',
    'uses'=>'ProductosController@searchType'
])->middleware('admin');
```

sería:

```php
<form action="{{ route('tipo', ['tipo' => $search]) }}" method="post">
```

pues el nombre de la ruta es `tipo`(`'as'=>'tipo'`) y el parámetro opcional, también es `tipo`(`{tipo?}`).
Lo que resultaría en:

```php
<form action="http://tu-dominio.com/admin/productos/el-valor-de-la-variable-search" method="post">
```

> Porque cuándo intento imprimir la variable me muestra $search en vez de el resultado que pido.

Esto es difícil responder pues no muestras como agregas la variable a la ruta, ni el código de cómo lo intentas imprimir.

---

**UPDATE:**
Acabo de probar esto y funciona:
**en blade:**

```php
@php($search = 'tipo')
<form action="{{route($search)}}" method="post">
    @csrf
    <input type="hidden" name="prueba" value="prueba">
    <button type="submit">Submmit Prueba</button>
</form>
```

**en web.php:**

```php
Route::post('admin/productos/{tipo?}', function () {
    return view('test');
})->name('tipo');
```

Al inspeccionar el elemento en el navegador:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Gracias, parece ser que acabo de llegar a la misma conclusión que tú hace unos minutos. De todas formas te estoy agradecido por la ayuda prestada y espero también ayudar en un futuro no muy lejano.